# Unicode Encode Error trying to send a numerical code via email using Python

Tags: python, email, unicode, automation, ascii

I am a beginner trying to send a personalized email using Python. I need to send a numerical code along with the message, and I'm using this code.

```
import smtplib
import ssl

def send_email(receive, pCode):
    port = 465

    sender = "mail@gmail.com"
    password = "passw"
    receive = sender  # For test purposes
    recipients = [{"receive": receive, "pCode": pCode}] # Also for test purposes

    message = """
    Subject: SUBJ
    
    CODE:
    {pCode}
    """

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    print("Starting to send")
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender, password)
        for recipient in recipients:
            server.sendmail(sender, recipient["receive"], message.format(pCode=pCode))

    print("email sent")



send_email("receive@gmail.com", '123456')
```

But when I run it, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MyPythonScripts/Iubi/PythonApps/emailSender.py", line 54, in <module>
    send_email("receive@gmail.com", '123456')
  File "C:/MyPythonScripts/Iubi/PythonApps/emailSender.py", line 48, in send_email
    server.sendmail(sender, recipient["receive"], message.format(pCode=pCode))
  File "C:\Users\Francesco Cambria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 859, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe8' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I really have tried everything, I've added `# encoding=utf8`
on top of my file, I've tried with `pCode = pCode.encode('utf8')` and some other solutions I found on stack overflow, but none seem to work, I'm getting always the same error.

Comment: Are there any non-ascii characters (that is, characters not in the English alphabet), in the email addresses, passwords or any other variables that you are using in the script?

Comment: @snakecharmerb all I'm using is an alphanumerical password, a normal email (with only letters in it), and the code. Without adding the code the email sends normally, but when I try with the code I get the error. Additionally, if this helps, I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if there is non-ASCII character in the message body.  @Hugo's answer should workaround this, but if you want to find out more, perhaps add the output of `print(message.format(pCode=pCode).encode('latin-1'))` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the message yourself like:

```
server.sendmail(sender, recipient["receive"], message.format(pCode=pCode).encode('utf-8'))
```